# c sharp mdi children в mdi parent вызывающего

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли из открытой формы являющейся MdiChildren по отношению к главному окну MdiParent вызвать форму для которой MdiParent будет являться главное окно?

И сразу переформулирую т.к. тяжело на слух воспринимается:
1. Есть главное окно 1.
2. В нём открыто дочернее окно 1.
3. Требуется в дочернем окне 1 открыть окно для которого родителем будет главное окно 1 а не дочернее окно 1.

Пробовал первое что в голову пришло:

`Form1 frm = new Form();
frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
frm.Show();`

В итоге получаю открытую форму которую нельзя взять в фокус.

Comment: А если в метод `Show` передать параметр-ссылку на родителя?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вызываю дочерняя 1:  `= new showForm(this);` В дочерней в конструкторе делаю переменную на всю `Form1 frm = переданная форма`. Пытаюсь открыть дочернюю форму с родительской переданной формы. `src.MdiParent = frm` . Получаю окно которое нельзя взять в фокус.